# Faking Composition and a Common Interface with Inheritance

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance

We're working with XML and want a common interface amongst the main XML class and all of its components.  However, sub-components of the XML class need additional methods, but they also need the main component's methods.  Seems like a great use for inheritance.

Here is some code I wrote to accomplish this task.  Hopefully, you can get a good idea of what we're going for based on usage:

```
using System;

namespace SampleNamespace
{
    public class SampleClass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            var xmlDocumentFiles = new XmlDocumentFiles();

            xmlDocumentFiles.Files.RootFile.SetFileName("Example.xml");

            System.Console.WriteLine(
                xmlDocumentFiles.Files.RootFile.GetFileName()
            );

        }
    }

    public class XmlDocumentFilesRoot
    {
        protected string _rootFileName;

        public FilesClass Files { get { return (FilesClass) this; } }
    }

    public class FilesClass : XmlDocumentFilesRoot
    {
        public RootFileClass RootFile { get { return (RootFileClass) this; } }
    }

    public class RootFileClass : FilesClass
    {
        public void SetFileName( string newTitle )
        {
            _rootFileName = newTitle;
        }

        public string GetFileName()
        {
            return _rootFileName;
        }
    }

    public class XmlDocumentFiles : RootFileClass
    {
    }

}
```

I was able to cast to child classes and to my surprise it runs just fine.  Assuming nothing is put inside of the sub-classes other than methods which wouldn't make sense in the parent, will there ever be any problems (weird compilation errors, runtime crashes) with this class structure?

Are there any alternatives?  I had initially tried nested classes + extension methods located outside of the main class, but there was a lot of code needed to set that up.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415717/using-c-sharp-extension-methods-on-not-in-nested-classes-to-establish-a-common

Answer (score 0):

Extending functionality of a class, sounds like a decorator pattern.

Here's a head-first pdf on this subject: 
http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfdesignpat/chapter/ch03.pdf

Also; I would like to discourage the triple '.' :

```
xmlDocumentFiles.Files.RootFile.SetFileName("Example.xml");
```

2 is evil, if you need 3: you will definitely lose maintainability.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Really?  You know, I don't disagree entirely, but our hope was actually that the pattern would provide some separation of concerns by not cluttering a single class with a ton of different methods.

Comment: @AlexanderPritchard : Think of it like this: if you'll continue this approach, you'll end up uses 4,5 maybe 6 dots. Imagine on of the objects returns a 'null' value, you'll get an NullReferenceException. Thats quite hard to debug in some cases. It can get worse: if you return a IDisposable somewhere, when will you perform the dispose? ... even worse: returning a Com object somewhere (i saw this case actually once): when do you call Marshall.Resease if required?

Comment: @AlexanderPritchard : For a really good example of a decorator pattern, take a look at the .net Stream class. There are quite a lot of different types (MemoryStream, StreamReader, StreamWriter, Images, HttpResponses etc.), all exposing their own methods, or implement their own (e.g. Write) overrides. It has all kinds of extra functionality within a class, without losing the base classes functionality. It is also easy to combine with interfaces, so you're not even stuck to the concrete implementation of one class :) I really think you should consider such a basic pattern in this case.

Comment: Thanks.  We'll explore the idea.